# Type 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: NetworkInfo

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Just started playing with the new AIR functions NetworkInfo and NetworkInterface, but can't build ...

This is the example I started from:
[tourdeflex](http://tourdeflex.adobe.com/AIR2samples/NetworkInfo/networkinfo.html)

But these lines cause errors:

```
var networkInfo:NetworkInfo = NetworkInfo.networkInfo;
var networkInterfaces:Vector.<NetworkInterface> = networkInfo.findInterfaces();
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Thanks a lot,
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution on the [adobe forum](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2921690#2921690)

Answer (score 0):

Are they run time errors or compile time errors?

The most common reason I see errors like that is because there is a version difference between a SWC and the Flex SDK that you are compiling your project against.

Comment: compile time ...

I'm compiling with SDK 4

Comment: Are you sure you're project is set up to USE AIR 2?  I'm pretty sure that NetworkInfo is an AIR 2 specific class.